# In tinymce, how to bind a mouseover event to insert menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce

In tinymce 4.x, there is the option to add an insert menu as seen below:

[image: Insert menu]

Is there any way to bind a mouseover event to this or any menu button? I have searched the documentation and I have had trouble finding how to bind events to buttons.

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE's toolbar buttons don't work as you wish - there is no configuration option to make your desired behavior happen.